# WordPress, how to run a function every 12 december?

Tags: wp-cron

I am a new WordPress developer and I want to build a custom interval for a function.

I have seen how to execute a script every one or five minutes, but I do not understand how an interval is calculated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot run script on every 12 December. WP Cron can be only defined as interval from first execution of script, so you have to execute script on 12 December with one year interval to do exactly what you want.

I will suggest you to create WP Cron job with daily interval and check in script if today is 12 December.

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_task_hook')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_task_hook');
}

add_action('my_task_hook', 'my_task_function');

function my_task_function() {
    $today = strtotime(date());
    if (date('d', $today) == '12' && date('m', $today) == '12') {
        // today is 12 December!
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember @Kdms, WP Cron is dependent on site visits it's not like native unix cron jobs

Comment: not that it's likely to make much difference, but I personally would check the month before the day. Technically it would slow things down a tiny bit because it would hit an extra test for all 31 days of december rather than just on every 12th of the month. But if your site has low traffic you are more likely to trigger on the days leading up to the 12th of december and you could potentially plan for this. This is perhaps an unlikely scenario though, and I hesitate to submit this comment, but if you have low traffic (or high traffic) you might want to consider all your options.

Answer (score 0):

To improve @Krzysztof Grabania's answer, you can modify your WP that way it works like a Unix cron job.
For that you have to put this line into your wp-config.php file:

`//Disable internal Wp-Cron function
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

This will turn off the while WP Cron. So your site will be faster, because it won't check every page load the actual tasks.

After that you have to set up a unix cron job for calling that URL:

`http://www.server.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

You should select the right interval wisely, because this will be the smallest interval all kind of scheduling. (I usually use 1-5 minutely cron)